# Ionic 4 blutooth printer not showing

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, thermal-printer

Is there any plugin available for **Blutooth POS printing** in ionic 4. I have searched a lot.. but didnt get any proper working solution. Normal printing is working with https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/printer. But blutooth devices are not showing.Any other method to do this ?

Comment: which printer ur using ...I have ngx 2inch thermal printer? It having connection issues..please let me know which device ur using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try **BluetoothSerial**

`ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-bluetooth-serial`

`npm install @ionic-native/bluetooth-serial`

for detailed info
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-print-on-a-bluetooth-printer-using-your-ionic-application-ceabc45abf75

Comment: is it supports portable Bluetooth thermal printer? I have ngx 2 inch thermal printer..it having connection issues? Some times I am getting no device found...some time it prints..Any specific reason? which device ur using...

Comment: Im using RPP300 Mobile Printer. Sometimes it print junk characters...Its because the connection issue between device and printer. Try Reconnecting device should work. If you are not connected previously make sure print service enabled in mobile settings

Comment: which plugin ur using?

Comment: if you need to use external print service use  [RawBT driver for thermal ESC/POS printer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.a402d.rawbtprinter)  or  [ESC POS Bluetooth Print Service](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.loopedlabs.escposprintservice)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using DatecsPrinter, it's a good plugin. It works for printing text, barcode and images.